# Is it possible to use iSpring Presenter component in a native x64 assembly?

Tags: c#, flash, 64-bit, powerpoint, ispring

Works well when set to x86, but don't work when set to x64.

Any ideas?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is closed.
The current (4.x) version of this software doesn't support native x64 mode.

x64 support is going to be supported in the next (5.x) versions.